# Facebook Unity SDK Android version requirement

Tags: facebook-unity-sdk

I cant seems to find it in the documentation, what is the android version requirement for Facebook Unity SDK v5.1 ?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

The android version requirement for the Facebook Unity SDK is the same minimum for Unity.